# How to access Greek letters in lyx

Tags: lyx

I need to use a lowercase lambda symbol.

The lyx documentation states that if I should be able to use the insert symbol, or copy and paste one into the document, but neither of these methods work.

I've had various error messages, firstly it was

```
"Error: Encoding file grenc.def not found"
```

Then in the terminal I ran the commands

```
sudo tlmgr install textgreek  
sudo tlmgr install greek-fontenc
```

And now the error message I get is

```
"LaTeX Error: This NFSS system is not set up correctly"
```

Is there any simple way to solve this problem? I've tried reinstalling lyx but that has not helped.

Comment: You can also write `$\lambda$` inside ERT.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem. For anyone else looking I ran the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-greek
sudo tlmgr install cbfonts
```

and it worked :)